# Android listview refresh only once

Tags: android, listview, refresh

I am really desperate, please help me.

In my main Activity I want to remove all items from the listview then add other data. I am able to delete the data and refresh the listview, but when I add new data, something strange happens. I insert the data in my Array. I call notifydatasetchanged on my adapter after every insertion. The adapter gets those items (I have confirmed this in debug mode). But the listview will not refresh. And now comes the VERY STRANGE thing: When I tap the back button on my device, the application quits (this part is ok), but for a moment before quitting it refreshes the listview with the correct data.

Here are some parts of my code:
For deleting the data I use:

```
newsArrayList = new ArrayList<NewsClass>();
Adapter = new NewsAdapter(this, newsArrayList);
lv.setAdapter(Adapter);
```

"lv" is my listview. The listview correctly loses all items and refreshes. I have also tried this:

```
newsArrayList.clear();
Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Also worked like expected. Then I use a "for" loop to add new items to my array, where I have the following lines:

```
newsArrayList.add(news[i]);
Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

As I wrote, when running in debug mode, everything seems fine. I have spent all day working on this problem. I have read several posts about similar issues on stackoverflow, I even watched a [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70&t=17m38s) on youtube. I am calling everything from the main UI thread.
I can work around this problem by restarting my activity, but I want to do it better than that. I have tried invalidate and such things, but nothing helped. Please note the VERY STRANGE thing, I wrote...
I think, that I have to force the activity to redraw its views, or something like that, but even refreshDrawableState(); on my listview did not help.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Don't notify the changes on your dataset until you do ALL the changes, clear, add and then notify, if not that will be VERY inefficient and can lead to memory/handles issues

Answer (score 0):

Basically If you want to clear list data then just call

```
newsArrayList.clear();
lv.setAdapter(null);
```

Again add what ever your data in ArrayList and set adapter

```
newsArrayList = new ArrayList<NewsClass>();
Adapter = new NewsAdapter(this, newsArrayList); // considering list with some elements
lv.setAdapter(Adapter);
```

If you are getting **outofmemory** error/exception then there is problem with your Adapter Class inside **getView** method